# Error running React Project/NEXTJS 404 Not Found

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run a React project that uses Nextjs but when I do the "yarn run dev" it doesn't load the project in the browser and the console gives me the following errors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1648081775573 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1648081775573 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1648081775573 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1648081775573 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1648081775573 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1648081775573 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1648081775573 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/development/_middlewareManifest.js?ts=1648081775573 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/logo_x.png 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/mock_bg.png 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/landing/rent.png 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/landing/high-five.png 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/landing/essential.png 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/landing/online.png 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/images/logo_x_white.png 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

It should be noted that the project is a shared repository which runs without problems in Windows, Linux and Mac environments. Is there something wrong with my machine?

PDTA: I tried "npm run dev" and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you post some code to help debug the issue? Are you using a starter (`create-next-app` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in NextJS 13 using src/app. Even my chunks/main-app.js is 404 (not found), my problem lies with my root directory name having white space i.e. project - front end (translates to project%20-%20front%20end). I solved this issue by cloning my repo and renaming it without whitespace i.e. (git clone <repository_url> <new_name_without_spaces>)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34700303)